# GraphView shows X-axis labels for points which are not data points

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have created a dummy app where I am trying to log the users data and generate a simple line graph out of it.

I am using GraphView to generate the graphs in my app.

User has to sign in using her gmail and then click on "Create" link in the navigation drawer to create a new statistic.

Now she can click on "List" link in the navigation drawer to see all the statistics created by her. Now on clicking a particular statistic, user should be able to view the graph as well as add new data into that particular statistic.

Everything is working fine except that graph shows labels for every single point on the X axis effectively creating an ugly black blot all along the x axis.

[This](https://github.com/tonysinghmss/LazyStats/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/tony/lazystats/fragments/StatsDisplay.java) is my code on Github.

Why GraphView is showing labels for the every point on the X axis?

**EDIT:**  I have attached my screenshot below. Check the X-axis. It is showing labels at every single point instead of just 2 points that I have entered.
[image]